# Assembly set font background color in DOS Graphics Mode

Tags: assembly, colors, x86-16, bios, dosbox

I tried to print colored background text in DOSBOX and the background always stays black .
Can anyone help me please?

```
model small
stack 256H
.data
.code

main :

MOV AX,13H
int 10h

MOV AH,09           ; FUNCTION 9
MOV AL,03           ; HEART ASCII
MOV BL,014H         ; PAGE 0, COLOR 14H
MOV CX,07D0H        ; 2000 CARACTERS
INT 10H             ; INTERRUPT 10 -> BIOS

end main
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UyLEL.png)

Comment: That looks like text mode, not bitmap graphics mode.  You're outputting a whole character glyph with a `3` for an ASCII heart, so that's pretty definitely text mode.

Comment: int10/09 does not support background in `BL` in 256 color graphics as the whole register is needed for the foreground. On some VGA bioses you can supply a background color in `BH`, but apparently not in dosbox.

Comment: Can you give me please another way to print text with colored bg in graphics mode? I can't find one that works.

Comment: I believe the best you can do is query the font and write the pixels yourself.

Comment: R U sure? It sounds ineffective..

Comment: No, I am not sure but I couldn't find anything else. Note that what the BIOS does behind the scenes might not be any more effective either (on a dumb VGA card anyway).

Comment: OK, I'll draw the text bg manually after each printing..

Comment: I mean it's not effective because this interrupt draws background in black and then I need to draw it in another color.